# I charge my phone 7 hours. I dont know why it is very slow to be fully charge

Tags: oppo-find-7

Honestly I use the wrong charger  but I dont really know what happen because it takes 7hours to be fully charged.

Comment: You use wrong charger as you say.

Answer (score 0):

> Honestly I use the wrong charger

Well there's your problem.

You most likely are using an underpowered charger. Find one that produces at least 1000mA(1A).

Comment: OP can use apps like Ampere to measure what current the charger is supplying to the battery and compare it with what current is actually needed to charge it healthily(which can be searched and found in internet). The fault may be in the charging cable too beacause aging and wear in cable provide larger resistance to the current through the cable.